# Do I have to take the trace over gamma matrices in Yukawa vertex correction?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization, feynman-diagrams, dirac-matrices, trace

Given the Yukawa coupling $\mathcal{L}_{\text{int}}=g\phi\bar{\psi}\psi$, if I want to compute the correction to one loop to the vertex, I would write something like this

$$\Lambda\sim  g\int\frac{d^dk}{(2\pi)^d}\frac{i}{(q\!\!/+k\!\!/)- m}\frac{i}{(p\!\!/-k\!\!/)-m}\frac{i}{k^2-M^2}$$

Do I have to take the trace over gamma matrices?

Comment: Have you tried writing out the explicit spinor or indices? This is the usual origin of trace terms when noticing that the indices indicate a trace be taken

Comment: Being a little "loose" with language, note that your vertex has two free dirac indices, which is what gets contracted with external spinors. Your one-loop vertex correction diagram should also have two free dirac indices, so to be fully correct you should keep this structure around when you do your integral.